# How do you rotate the view in Megapolis?

Tags: megapolis

In Megapolis on the iPad how do you rotate the view so you can see behind large/tall buildings?

I can rotate individual buildings but not the whole view/city.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, there is no such feature. You cannot rotate the map / view in Megapolis.